# Understanding the Union of Cartesian Products

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

My question might be trivial but unfortunately cannot create a picture of understanding it.

Suppose that we have the set $E$ can take only two values $0$ and $1$

$$E=\left \{ 0,1 \right \}$$

and that $E^{0}=\varnothing$. Then the m-fold product is $$E^{m}= E\times E \times ...\times E= \left \{(e,e,...,e):e\in E, \ \  m  \ times \right \}$$

From my understanding this cartesian product $E^{m}$ can be of the form $(0,0,...,0)$ or $(0,1,...,1)$ etc. However, I came across to the following definition
$$E^{*}=\cup _{0}^{\infty}E^{m} $$
which confused me quite a lot. I tried to expand it as
$$E^{0} \ \cup E^{1} \cup \ E^{2} \ \cup ... = \varnothing \ \cup E \ \cup (E\times E) \ \cup... = E \ \cup (E\times E) \ \cup... $$

Is this set, $E^{*}$, going to contain all the possible vectors of $0, 1$ of infinite length ???

Because as I understand it, it will be a set that will contain $\left \{(e),(e,e),(e,e,e),...  \right \}$ for all the possible configurations of $e\in \left \{ 0,1 \right \}$

Comment: No, if it contains a vector $v$ of infinite length then $\exists m \in \mathbb N$ such that $v \in E^m$.

Comment: $E^0$ should be a set with *one element* (the empty sequence).

Answer (score 1):

No. If it contains a vector $v$ of infinite length, then $\exists m \in\mathbb N$ such that
$v \in E^m$.

The set $E^\infty$ is basicly the set of all the finite binary sequences, and this space is not complete.